# Visual studio 2012 SharePoint 2013 solution error: "user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, web-parts, ascx

So I was creating a SharePoint 2013 visual web part on Visual Studio 2012 and came to this problem. Visual Studio automatically creates `WebPartUserControl.ascx.cs` and `WebPartUserControl.ascx.g.cs`. the `WebPartUserControl.ascx.g.cs` is generated automatically when you edit the `WebPartUserControl.ascx` file. So I've added a couple of `ContentTemplate` tags into `.ascx` file and Visual Studio generated this code in `WebPartUserControl.ascx.g.cs` :

```
public partial class WebPartUserControl {
   ...

   public static implicit operator global::System.Web.UI.TemplateControl(WebPartUserControl target)
   {
       return target == null ? null : target.TemplateControl;
   }

   ...
}
```

When I try to deploy the solution, Visual Studio underlines the `implicit operator global::System.Web.UI.TemplateControl` and I get this error:

```
Namespace.WebPart.WebPartUserControl.implicit operator 
System.Web.UI.TemplateControl(Namespace.WebPart.WebPartUserControl)': 
user-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed
```

I don't even imagine how to solve this even though im struggling on this issue for a couple of hours now... Can somebody help me, please? I assume I have to add something to the `.ascx` file or to `WebPartUserControl.ascx.cs` maybe? Thanks in advance!